# Dapper with SQLite and C# Error "Insufficient parameters supplied to the command"

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper, system.data.sqlite

New Information since the original post. This code successfully retrieves an entity, which makes me think QueryMultiple maps differently than Query. Is that true?

```
 using (var multi = sqlConn.QueryMultiple(sqlStmt, new { MytableId = mytableinstance.MytableId }))
 {
    var fullEnt = multi.Read<MytableSource>();
 }
```

---

What I want to do is use Dapper to query a child table based on the FK column value of the parent, with SQLite as the database. The below code gives me the error

> Insufficient parameters supplied to the command

Could anyone point me to my error?

*Note - I am also using Dapper.Contrib. .NET Framework 4.7.2.*

Thanks.

---

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = '1';

CREATE TABLE "Mytable" (
    "MytableId" INTEGER Primary Key AutoIncrement,
    "MytableName"   TEXT UNIQUE,
    "Stamp" TEXT 
);


CREATE TABLE "MytableSource" (
    "MytableSourceId"   INTEGER Primary Key AutoIncrement,
    "MytableId" INTEGER,
    "SourceBlob"    BLOB,
    "Stamp" TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY("MytableId") REFERENCES "Mytable"("MytableId")

);
```

---

```
    [Table("Mytable")]
    public class Mytable
    {
        [Key]
        public long MytableId { get; set; }

        public String MytableName { get; set; }

        public String Stamp { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("MytableSource")]
    public class MytableSource
    {
        [Key]
        public long MytableSourceId { get; set; }

        public long MytableId { get; set; }

        public String SourceBlob { get; set; }

        public String Stamp { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
    var sqlStmt = "Select * From MytableSource Where MytableId = @MytableId";
                var sqlConn = new SQLiteConnection( this.ConnectionString );
                using ( sqlConn )
                {
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    var fullEnt = sqlConn.Query<MytableSource>(sqlStmt, new SQLiteParameter("@MytableId" , mytableinstance.MytableId )).FirstOrDefault();
                    this.MytableSourceCurrent = fullEnt;

                }
```

unknown error
Insufficient parameters supplied to the command

Comment: Try `new SQLiteParameter("MytableId", ...)` perhaps?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I tried that (removing the @) and got the same result. Thanks.

Comment: What about `.Query<MytableSource>(sqlStmt, new { MytableId = mytableinstance.MytableId })` ?

Comment: Although the example in the question looks fine, my issue was due to the Dapper limitation mentioned at [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/dapper-limitations)

`SQLite parameter names are case-sensitive. Ensure that the parameter names used in SQL match the case of the anonymous object's properties.`

My class property name's case was different from the parameter's case.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the original code from GitHub, searched for `Query< T >` and manually traced through only a few methods.  Although it's highly abstract and documentation is sparse, the code itself at least reveals that an `IEnumerable` object is expected.  It seems to prefer the `Dapper.IDynamicParameters` object for the collection, but beyond that it wasn't worth trudging through the code to get more details.

This worked for me in testing:

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
param.Add("@MytableId" , mytableinstance.MytableId);
var fullEnt = sqlConn.Query<MytableSource>(sqlStmt, parameters ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for digging into that. I still don't understand why GET does not accept a parameter that is a foreign key, and only uses a PK, and requires a full SQL statement if I want to use a FK to query. If I have to write a whole SQL statement I lose most of the ORM value. Not your fault obviously, and I appreciate again you checking.